# Phonegap built android project. I got an error: Config cannot be resolved

Tags: android, cordova

Below is the code...
Does anyone have any idea what is the problem?

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class Expo extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the full code?   Don't you need the project name at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have config.xml into /res/xml folder?